# React Material-ui TreeView/TreeItem causes: "Uncaught Error: Material-UI: withStyles is not longer exported from @material-ui/core/styles"

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to debug a react app that uses TreeView/TreeItem. When I use them in a nearly empty app, it causes the screen to go white and the only error in the console is

```
Uncaught Error: Material-UI: withStyles is not longer exported from @material-ui/core/styles.
You have to import it from @material-ui/styles.
See https://material-ui.com/r/migration-v4/#material-ui-core-styles for more details.
    at withStyles (withStyles.js:3:1)
    at ./node_modules/@material-ui/lab/esm/TreeView/TreeView.js (TreeView.js:742:1)
    at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)
    at fn (hot module replacement:62:1)
    at ./src/App.js (bundle.js:18:83)
    at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)
    at fn (hot module replacement:62:1)
    at ./src/index.js (App.js:16:1)
```

I don't use withStyles anywhere, so I don't know what that means.

Here's my App.js

```
import './App.css';
import * as React from "react";
import TreeView from "@material-ui/lab/TreeView";
import TreeItem from "@material-ui/lab/TreeItem";

function App() {
    return (
        <div>
            <TreeView>
                <TreeItem nodeId={"1"} label={"test"}/>
            </TreeView>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "testing-module",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": ".",
  "proxy": "http://localhost:3000",
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.6",
    "@emotion/style": "^0.8.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.6",
    "@material-ui/core": "^5.0.0-beta.5",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.3",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.61",
    "@material-ui/styles": "^4.11.5",
    "@mui/material": "^5.11.13",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.9.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. I have been stuck on this for quite some time. Please let me know if I should give any more information

I've tried using Chrome and Firefox. Same error in both places.

I tried copy and pasting the example they use at https://mui.com/material-ui/react-tree-view/ and that resulted in the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the problem is that you are using inconsistent versions of mui?

1. Try `"@material-ui/core": "^4.12.3"` instead of `"@material-ui/core": "^5.0.0-beta.5`"
2. Or Migrate everything to v5 - you are already have `"@mui/material": "^5.11.13"` as dependency

Comment: Number 1 worked, thanks!